# matplotlib 3D surface - gaps / holes in surface

Tags: python, matplotlib, surface, mplot3d

A grid is interpolated with scipy's `griddata()` and contains values and NaNs. However, when the grid is plotted with mplot3d's `plot_surface()` there are gaps in the surface (see upper plot). The lower the view height, the more of such gaps are rendered. When the grid is plotted in 2D with `imshow()` there are no gaps (see lower plot).

Comparison `plot_surface` and `imshow`

[image]

Here is a close-up:

[image]

I couldn't find an answer to this problem and I am wondering whether this is a known issue.

This small example reproduces the problem: ([data.txt](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bf886433298528bfa2f0f80448ddaa6b))

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

Z = np.loadtxt('data.txt')
X = np.linspace(0,3,301)
Y = np.linspace(0,3,301)
X = np.array([X,]*(301)).transpose()
Y = np.array([Y,]*(301))
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,15), dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1, projection='3d')
plt.hold(True)
ax.view_init(40,300)
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap='jet', rstride=1, cstride=1, antialiased=False, shade=False, alpha=1.0, linewidth=0, vmin=0.25, vmax=0.35);

ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.dist = 11

ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.hold(True)
plt.imshow(Z, cmap='jet', vmin=0.25, vmax=0.35, origin='lower');

plt.show()
```

Comment: I think this is the expected behavior for `np.nan`, the patch touching the invalid points are not drawn.  I am not sure that there are not gaps in the imshow, they might just be thin.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look at my problem. I checked the underlying grid and it is continously filled with values in this area. Moreover, the gaps change with a different viewing height or angle.

Comment: I can confirm that the problem is reproducible and does not depend on the data, but rather on the viewing angle. The effect of missing vertices is the more pronounced that shallower the viewing angle. It is also independent on the parameters like `antialiased`, `shade` or `linewidth`.

Comment: Thanks for running the example and confirming the problem. It is also independent on `cmap`.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem also with matplotlib 2.0

Comment: Posted as an issue on [github/matplotlib](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8222)